# D3.js - Data and Axis Not Synchronized During Pan

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I created a scatter plot using D3.js that updates every 20 seconds.  It also pans and zooms.  The problem is the data lags behind the axis during the pan.  I've looked for examples of a similar implementation but all I can find are ones that either do zoom/pan or do intervals, not both.  I can't find the source of the problem.  A simplified demo of my code can be found here: http://jsbin.com/yurik/1/edit.  Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The synchronization issue comes from the fact that you are using a transition to move the circles and *not* using a transition to update the x-axis. Here's the relevant snippet from the `draw` function:

```
circles.transition()
  .attr("cx", function(d) { return x(dateFn(d)) })
  .attr("cy", function(d) { return yValueFn(d) });

svg.selectAll("g.x.axis").call(xAxis);
```

Because D3 has [a default transition duration of 250 milliseconds](https://github.com/mbostock/d3/wiki/Transitions#duration), the circles are lagging behind the axis, which is updated instantly. You can synchronize the two by reducing the transition duration to 0 like this:

```
circles.transition().duration(0)
```

That should make the x-axis and circles move synchronously.